# WKWebKit View overlaps status bar on iOS 10 but not iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am programmatically creating a web view with this code

```
var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
```

On iOS 11 the web view top bounds are at the bottom of the status bar but on iOS 10 the web view covers the entire screen including the clock, battery, etc... across the top.

I tried making adjustments to the view controller in the inspector but nothing seems to have any affect.

Is there a way to prevent the web view from filling the entire screen?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Where would I insert that into the code that I have?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. The view controller did not even display.

Comment: show some screenshots, please.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably work:

```
webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Comment: 'contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually fix the problem but have added:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

as a suitable workaround.